# OpenCV java Face detection NullPointerException

Tags: java, opencv

I am learning OpenCV java in mac. I am trying out the tutorial online but getting **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

here are my code

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;


public class testApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(testApp.class
                        .getResource("/Users/myName/Downloads/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")
                        .getPath());

        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(testApp.class
                        .getResource("lena.png")
                        .getPath());

        MatOfRect faceD = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image,faceD);
        for (Rect rect:faceD.toArray()){
            Imgproc.rectangle(image,new Point(rect.x,rect.y),new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0,255,0));
        }

        String outputFile = "OUTPUT.png";
        //System.out.println(String.format("writing %s", outputFile));
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(outputFile,image);

    }
}
```

the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testApp.main(testApp.java:13)
```

how can I solve this, thanks in advance

Comment: You did not give the line numbers, so which line is the exception about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `.getResource("/Users/myName/Downloads/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")` returns `null`, because it can't find the resource. Therefore I would suggest you to check if the path above is correct.

Comment: the haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml is on the given path. how can i fix that ?

Comment: It's hard to assume not having the mac and the exact directory with the file. Did you try any other approach? For example, you may substitute your code of initializing `CascadeClassifier` with the following: `CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("/Users/myName/Downloads/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");`

Comment: That was the issue. now its working fine . thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported MatOfReact?:
`import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;`

Answer (score 0):

i think it does not load the xml file so the default opencv constructor for CascadeClassifier is like this

```
CascadeClassifier::Cascade`Classifier(const string& filename)
```

Example:

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    face_cascade.load( "C:/OpenCV243/data/Haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );
```